# Catch "Try Again" with ionic speech recognition

Tags: ionic-framework, speech-recognition, ionic4, ionic-native

I am using Ionic Native speech recognition as outlined in the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/speech-recognition:

```
startListening() {
    this.speechRecognition.startListening()
      .subscribe(
        (matches: Array<string>) => {
          console.log(matches)
        },
        (onerror) => {
          console.log('error:', onerror)
        }
     )
}
```

However, this only listens for a certain amount of time. If nothing has been said, or the speech was unable to hear it, I receive the message "Tap to speak. Try again". However, for this the user needs to press a button to be able to speak again. Is there therefore a way to catch when this happens such that I can trigger `this.startListening()` again?

Answer (score 0):

I find in the doc, the speech recognition only 5 times and after that it stop.

https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition.

You can start listening with options :

`let options = {
  String language,
  Number matches, // increase this number if don't want  to stop listening
  String prompt,      // Android only
  Boolean showPopup,  // Android only
  Boolean showPartial 
}`

`this.speechRecognition.startListening(options)
  .subscribe(
    (matches: Array<string>) => console.log(matches),
    (onerror) => console.log('error:', onerror)
  )`

Comment: Any idea how to extend the 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes like I say  in the option  you can set the number matches to what you want like 1500. And its not 5 secondes its 5 match

Comment: `let options = {      matches: 1000   }`

Comment: It says in the docs:  {Number} number of return matches (default 5, on iOS: maximum number of matches). Thats not what I was asking right?

Comment: @JohnAndrews You found out how can this be achieved? Extending the 5 seconds time?